Do crystals respawn (or can they be mined) in Planet Crafter?
Do the crystals (pulsar quartz, blazar quartz, magnetar quartz, quasar quartz, and solar quartz) respawn?
If not, can they be mined? I only have a few magnetar quartz and I'm afraid to use them if I can only get them from exploring wrecks.

If you go through to other crashes you can get the new Quartz (all four colors) decoder chips, to craft later. Also you can't use storage buildings to send drones to and from, but the storage on cars works to send drones to and from
